# Distributing books among students

Tags: combinatorics

5 distinct books are to be distributed among 3 students.

In how many ways can this action be carried out?

[image]

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: all books must be distributed?

Comment: well nothing about that is stated!

Comment: one kid can get 5 books and the others nothing , true that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have seen from comments and your own answer attempt, there are several different interpretations to this problem.

In each of the following interpretations, **only one copy of each book exists**.  This seems to be different than in your interpretation where you allowed all three students to get five books each somehow...

- Interpretation 1:  Each book must be used and each student must get a book:

As shown by Rohan, if we assume each student must get at least one book, there are $3\cdot\binom{5}{3,1,1} + 3\cdot\binom{5}{2,2,1}=60+90=150$ ways to distribute the books

- Interpretation 2:  Not every book needs to be used and each student must get a book:

We get in addition to the $150$ ways from the earlier interpretation, also the **2-1-1** and **1-1-1** cases to consider, adding an additional $3\cdot\binom{5}{2,1,1,1}+\binom{5}{2,1,1,1}=180+60$ ways for a total of $150+240=390$ arrangements.

- Interpretation 3: Not every book needs to be used and some students are allowed to get no books

Approaching via multiplication principle, choose for each book to either go to the first student, the second student, the third student, or the bookshelf (*unused*), for a total of four choices for each book.  This gives a total of $4^5=1056$ arrangements

- Interpretation 4: Every book needs to be used and some students are allowed to get no books

Just like in the last interpretation except books aren't allowed to be put back on the shelf, giving three options for each book.  This gives a total of $3^5=243$ arrangements.

This fourth interpretation is the most usual interpretation of the problem and is the one that the given answer key seems to use.

---

"*Where did I go wrong*"

You appear to have approached via multiplication principle, but what you are counting does not appear to be what we intend to count.

You counted the number of ways in which each of the three students can pick a number from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ where at least one of the students picked a nonzero number.

This does not unfortunately count the number of ways that the books can be distributed since a result of $(3,1,1)$ it is ambiguous which of the three books student1 got.  Further, it counts outcomes like $(5,5,5)$ which you seem to suggest refers to student1 getting $5$ books, student2 also getting $5$ books, and student3 getting $5$ books... but how is that possible when there are only five books total?  Are they sharing books?  I'd think not.

Comment: in the first interpretation wont it be $3!\cdot\binom{5}{3,1,1} + 3!\cdot\binom{5}{2,2,1}$

Answer (score 0):

Each book can be assigned to a student in $3$ distinct ways, so the answer must be $3^5$.